# I enabled "Run in background" while downloading plug-ins in Android-Studio 2.1.2. Now I can't find my way out to enable it again. What to do?

Tags: android-studio

I am very new to environment of Android-Studio and after enabling "Run in background" while downloading a plug-in, I don't know how to restore that default pop-up window showing status of downloading plug-in.

Please give step by step way to get it back.

Answer (score 12):

You can go in menu "Window -> Background Tasks -> Show".
I hope your download is complete by this time. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Close the SDK list window using 'Cancel'. Now you will be able to see "Events" just left of "Configure". Click on it to see currently running installations.
Hope it helps!